# What information is shared with immigration deparments when clearing customs/immigration?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal

When a US citizen enters a foreign country and passes through immigration, what information (especially information provided by the US) is available to the foreign government besides the information printed on the passport or stored in any chip that may be present in the passport?

Comment: Sorry, but how exactly does this relate to travel? It seems overly broad and yet oddly specific.

Comment: Only USA and Canadian police agencies have real-time access. However, the UK, Australia and NZ immigration authorities have theoretical access. The way it works is as follows: you apply for your Visa using your biometrics at any of these three countries. Anonymous (without any other identifying information) fingerprints queries are sent to the Canadian RCMP database. Here, fingerprints are compared against the criminal, immigration and refugee repositories. If there is a match, data is shared. Works the same way for the USA CPIC. Unless you apply for a Visa, it's highly unlikely they will know

Comment: The way your question reads its seems like you are on a fishing trip in order to satisfy some unspecified condition.  As has been previously stated this makes your question overly broad and subject to being closed (rightly so).  You will have more success if if you simply state "I am subject to condition X, what countries can I travel to without divulging it?"  However the caveat is that supporting illegal activities is not condoned here, and that you are unlikely to be helped if you are trying to escape justice for a crime you have committed.

Comment: I've no idea why people are voting to close this as "too broad" when the overriding point is that it's completely off-topic. When we tell somebody that a question is too broad, the right response from them is to edit it to make it more specific (e.g., "Does Mexico have access?") but that's a total waste of their time, since then we'll say "OK, but this is a question about co-operation between law enforcement agencies, not a question about travelling."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the international co-operation of law enforcement agencies, not about travel.

Comment: @DavidRicherby You stated you're voting to close because my question is off-topic, yet above it says it was put on hold because it's too broad. Please clarify which is it exactly so I can fix it.

Comment: @TravelMate Unfortunately, if people give multiple reasons, the site claims that everybody voted for the majority. In this case, four people voted "too broad" and I voted "off-topic". Really, I don't see how this question is about travel _at all_.

Comment: @DavidRicherby You've never been though immigration when you traveled? I will split my question and rephrase it. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @TravelMate Of course I’ve been through immigration. But your question isn’t about going through immigration. It’s about how law enforcement agencies share information. You’re asking about how law enforcement agencies work, and that’s not a travel question. Travel questions are “I’m a traveller. How does X work?”